# Angular 6+ / Retry Service Call on Error Callback?

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, rxjs, observable

I have an implementation of a service call which might throw an error, is it possible to rerun the service call if it errors out?

```
captureMultiScreen(elem: Alert, overwrite: boolean, success?: Function, failed?: Function) {
this.spinnerValue = true;
const captureModel: Capture = {
  member_id: elem.member_id,
  gateway: elem.gateway,
  account: elem.account,
  alert_id: elem.alert_id,
  transaction_id: elem.transaction_id,
  overwrite: overwrite
};

this.captureService.CaptureScreenService(captureModel).subscribe(result => {
  this.capServiceResponse = result;
},
(error) => {
  // Retry "CaptureScreenService" here
}
```

Is there a way to just run the service call again if it reached the error callback?

Comment: Take a look to the retry operation of RxJS https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#retry-failed-observable

Comment: @sanfalero I see, and this `retry()` method should be called in the same function where I make my http request?

Comment: You can use it on any observable. Maybe something like this.captureService.CaptureScreenService(captureModel).pipe(retry(3)).subscribe(...

Comment: @sanfalero worked like a charm! Thank you; if you'd like to put this as an answer I'll select it as accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [retry function](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#retry-failed-observable). In your code it would be something like:

```
this.captureService.CaptureScreenService(captureModel)
  .pipe(retry(3)).subscribe(...)
```